# Inheritance won't work using super(), but it works with explicit __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the reason for my issue here, on Google, and on YouTube with no success.

```
class Profession:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Wizard(Profession):
    def __init__(self, name, spell):
        # Profession.__init__(self, name)
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(name)
        self.spell = spell

class Archer(Profession):
    def __init__(self, name, attack):
        # Profession.__init__(self,name)
        super(Archer, self).__init__(name)
        self.attack = attack

class Rogue(Wizard,Archer):
    def __init__(self, name, spell, attack):
        super(Rogue, self).__init__(spell, name)
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(attack, name)


wizard = Wizard('Magic', 'Abrakadabra')
archer = Archer('Robin Hood', 'Arrow')

print(wizard.name, wizard.spell)
print(archer.name, archer.attack)

rogue = Rogue('Dodgy', 'Spell', 'Attack')
print(rogue.name, rogue.spell, rogue.attack)
```

It errors out once I try to initialise 'rogue' object.

```
TypeError: Archer.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attack'
```

When I use explicit `__init__`, everything works.

Comment: `super` calls the _next_ implementation in the method resolution order. What that is in `__init__` depends on what's currently being created. You need to read up on _cooperative_ inheritance - `Wizard` and `Archer` aren't written such that they can both be inherited by a single class.

Comment: Thanks for directing me, I have never heard of such a term as 'cooperative inheritance'. I am just starting my adventure with programming. All the best, mate, take care 